# Accessing positions in lists

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x

Can someone please help me understand why accessing list positions in the second example is not counting the first position `'0'`?

```
>>> A = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> A[2]
'c'  # this is as I expect

>>> A = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4']
>>> A[2]
'2'  # why is this outcome '2'? I expected it to be '1'
```

Comment: What? Why do you expect to get items at *different* indices out of the two lists **for the same index?!** You get the third letter (`'c'`) and the third number (`'2'`), so what's the problem?

Comment: you must be joking. in both examples you are getting 3. element counting from 1. or second counting from 0.

Comment: Why did you not expect the first example to return `'b'` then? If you look at both lists, you can see that `'2'` and `'c'` are in the same position in their respective lists.

Comment: I'm new to Programing and some things do not immediately make sense to me.

Comment: @Rutra: I can see that people can get confused over 0-based indexing vs. 1-based indexing, but your example shows your confusion is different. And I am confused by that confusion.

Comment: As I see it , when I call to print specific list position from A list it will always count from 0 and print whatever is at the specific list position. in the first example it checks OK and in the second why it does differently ? My list understanding is that regardless what is in the list it always counts from position  0

Comment: @Rutra: that's where we are confused. `'2'` *is at position 2* in the list. At 0 you have the string `'0'`, at 1 you have `'1'`, and at 2 you have `'2'`. What makes you think that that is not the case?

Comment: lets say the list contains 5 items in it , when you call item number in the list [2] you will get item 3 as it will count 0,1,2 yes? and this looks right to me as you can see in the first example .  However when I have list with numbers ['zero','one','two','three'] and I call position [2] I should get 'one'  that is where I'm confused.

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is, can you treat numbers in the list, if a list contains numbers the same way as any other items as strings?  When you call a position in the string will it always count starting from 0? or i should look differently at numbers if they are part of the list.

Comment: @Rutra: so you are subtracting 1 *twice*. You get the *third* item for `2`. Because the items are number 0, 1 and 2. What puzzles me is how you did not get confused the same way in your first example.

Comment: @Rutra when you ask for `mylist[2]`, you will **always** get the third item in the list, regardless of what the list contains - letters, numbers, objects, whatever. I am thoroughly confused as to why you expect one list to follow that rule, and another list to not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break it down:

```
>>> A = [ 'a',   'b',       'c',        'd',   'e']
          A[0]   A[1]     >>A[2]<<      A[3]   A[4] 

>>> A[2]
'c' #Third item in list? - Yes


>>> A = [ '0',   '1',       '2',        '3',   '4']
          A[0]   A[1]     >>A[2]<<      A[3]   A[4] 

>>> A[2]
'2' #Third item in list? - Yes
```

Python lists always start indexing at `0`

Comment: OMG- i feel bad , overcomplicating such obvious thing. Too much material in too short time can fry your brain - I guess that is my case.

Answer (score 0):

In both cases, `A[2]` is referencing whatever is stored in index `2` of the list. For

```
A = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

This is `'c'`. (Note that due to zero-based counting `'a'` is at index `0`)

In the same way `A[2]` for

```
A = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4']
```

references index `2` which yields a value of `'2'`.